# How to Mine Ether and use Ethereum on Windows?

Tags: mining, installation, clients, windows

Which programs should be installed and what do you need to do to start mining Ether and use Ethereum?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[Here](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/guides/how-to-mine-ethereum/) is a guide you may find useful:

- Download Ethereum Software
- Setup Ethereum Software
- Download Mining Software
- Setup Mining Software
- Mine

**Step 1: Download Geth**

The first thing you need to do is go to this link download [Geth](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/).

Geth is the program that communicates with the Ethereum Network and acts as the a relay between your computer, its hardware and the rest of the ethereum network computers so if a block is mined by another computer your Geth program will pick it up and then pass on the new information onto your GPU or CPU for mining.

**Step 2: Unzip GETH**

You need to unzip the GETH file and move it to a location on your hard drive. (Right click on the zipped file and select unpack.)

In this case we'll move it to the hard drive, usually (C:) - which will make the next step easier. All you need to do is copy the file you have downloaded and unzipped and move it to the hard drive folder.

**Step 3: Start Command Prompt**

Now you need to run the program you just downloaded. To do this you need to run Command Prompt. You can do this by searching in the search function in Windows for "CMD" and then clicking on it when it shows up.

**Step 4: cd Into Root Directory**

Command Prompt is now open. (It can look terrifying to people who aren't familiar with it!)

The Command Prompt box usually has

```
C:\Users\Username>
```

showing in it - where Username is your username - so if you log into your computer with the username cryptocompare, then the command prompt box will open with:

```
C:\Users\cryptocompare
```

You need to tell the computer to look in another place. Into the newly opened command prompt, type:

```
cd /
```

You should now see:

```
C:\>
```

You have just used the `cd` command or "change directory" command to make command prompt look at the `C:/` drive.

**Step 5: Create Geth Account**

You need to tell your Geth program to create a new account. As you have installed it in your user directory in Step 2,  it is just a simple case of typing in:

```
geth account new
```

and then pressing return/enter.

It should look like this:

```
C:\>geth account new
```

**Step 6: Create Password**

After hitting the enter button in Step 5, you will be asked to enter a password. N.B. You will not be able to see what you are typing in, so type it carefully. This is the password that locks your account and keeps your Private key safe.

*If you lose this password, you will lose all your Ether attached to the wallet held by that Private key!*

Once you have entered your password, and confirmed it by entering it a second time, you will have created a new account. Congratulations, your about a third of the way there!

**Step 7: Connect to Ethereum**

You need to tell your Geth Program to start communicating with the rest of the Ethereum network. You do this by typing:

```
geth --rpc
```

This should look like:

```
C:\> geth --rpc
```

Press enter, and the screen should start downloading the blockchain for Ethereum. At this point, you are synchronising with the rest of the Ethereum network. Sometimes your fire wall can block this process. If so, just click "Allow access."

**MINING**

**Step 8: Download Mining Software**

Now you need to download Ethminer, which makes your GPU or CPU run the hashing algorithm that is integral to securing the Ethereum ??network through proof of work.?? You can download this [here](http://cryptomining-blog.com/tag/ethminer-cuda-download/). (Be sure to scroll down to the bottom of the page to get the right version. The latest and most up to date one is right at the end.)

**Step 9: Install Mining Software**

Click on the downloaded file and select "Install". Your firewall can cause issues, but just click "Allow", if the firewall announces that a connection to the Internet has been blocked. The same is true if Windows  doesn't recognise or approve the software. Tell windows it is OK, if asked. Click through the installation process, until Ethminer is installed.

**Step 10: Start Command Prompt**

You need to open up another command prompt, as in step 4. You are going to see two scary looking boxes! Simply right click on your already opened command prompt, in the taskbar at the bottom of the page,and click on the command prompt in the menu that appears.

A new command prompt should open, showing:

```
C:\users\username
```

This is the wrong place to look for etherminer, so you need to tell it the right place to find it.

**Step 11: Navigate to Etherminer directory**

Into the newly opened command prompt, type:

```
cd /
```

It should look like this:

```
C:\users\username>cd /
```

Then tap "Enter". You should now see:

```
C:\>
```

You have just used the `cd` command, or "change directory" command, to make the command prompt look at the `C:/` drive, not your user file.

**Step 12: cd Into "Program Files"**

Type in:

```
cd prog
```

Then tap the <kbd>Tab</kbd>. This should look like this:

```
C:\>cd prog
```

Then tap <kbd>Tab</kbd>, which will automatically complete the phrase for the closest fit, found in the C: drive, just like autotext does on your iPhone.

After tapping <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you should see:

```
C:/> cd "Program Files"
```

Tap "Enter", which should give you a new line saying:

```
C:\Program Files>
```

**Step 13: cd Into Ethereum Folder**

Type in:

```
cd eth
```

and then tap <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will take you into the newly installed Ethereum Mining software folder.

It should look like this, after tapping <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```
C:\Program Files>cd "Ethereum (++) 0.9.39
```

(Perhaps the version numbers a the end will differ.)

Tapping <kbd>Enter</kbd> should give you:

```
C:\Program Files\Ethereum (++) 0.9.39>
```

This will look slightly different depending on the version!

**Step 14: cd Into Release Folder**

Type in:

```
cd release
```

and tap "Enter". This should give you the line as follows:

```
C:\Program Files\Ethereum (++) 0.9.39\Release>
```

**Step 15: GPU mining**

Type in:

```
ethminer -G
```

and tap "Enter", and you should then start mining with your GPU (the best way), after building a DAG file, which can take around ten minutes.

There can be problems at this point. For example:

- Insufficient Memory

The program might say that you have insufficient memory on your Graphics card to mine Ether, with Ethereum's Ethash algorithm. If this is the case, you can still mine with your CPU, or go out and buy a new graphics card! If you get an error message like this, tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, to cancel the process. Then you can either retry it, or alternatively, move onto step 16,  and mine with your CPU, rather than your GPU.

**Step 16 CPU mining**

Type in:

```
ethminer
```

and tap <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and you will start mining with your CPU. Again, you will need to create a DAG file, the first time you do this, which can take some time. But after that is complete, your "Geth" program downloaded in step 1 should start talking to your "ethminer" program, and you should start mining!

Please note if the above doesn't work.  The real fun part starts - debugging =/  Good luck!

Comment: Answers that are just links aren't very helpful here.  Can you please give some details in the post?

Comment: [This (1.0.8)](http://cryptomining-blog.com/7844-new-ethminer-0-9-41-genoil-1-0-8-windows-binary/) is the last version for the mining software (ethminer) now. For a list of all versions: http://cryptomining-blog.com/tag/ethminer-download/

Comment: @high110 everything is going perfectly except ethminer says `JSON-RPC problem. Probably couldn't connect. Retrying in 1...` forever. And geth won't mine with more than 1 GPU with the -mine option.

Comment: I believe the binaries no longer download from there. I got to this link: https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/ from what I assume is their github page: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum

Comment: Please update the link to download Geth.

Comment: The link to Ethminer seems to be broken