# Ethminer install error

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum, ethminer

I want to start mining in windows server 2008
( [How to Mine Ether and use Ethereum on Windows?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/110/how-to-mine-ether-and-use-ethereum-on-windows))
 everything is going perfectly except ethminer(step 9) says JSON-RPC problem. Probably couldn't connect. Retrying in 1... forever. And geth won't mine

what should I do?

Comment: Can you post more details of error log?

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake thank for answear.I reinstall and it work now.I am new at the eth mining.I just install geth and ethminer.exe ....is this enough? Now in my server geth and ethminer are working.... Will my mining work?Where will I will get coin from mining?Should I create wallet and sync with geth or ethminer? here is working : https://i.hizliresim.com/o6Vly9.png  is it working?

Comment: AFAIK, that is enough to run a full node and mine, you better ask a new question if you need a full detailed answer

Comment: thanks,I asked here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29728/minimum-requirement-for-ether-mining

Comment: Hi there. If you managed to get this working by reinstalling, then it's unlikely your question can ever be answered. Just to keep things clean, I'd suggest closing/deleting this question and concentrating on your new one :-)

Comment: I open new question :(   https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29763/ethminer-exe-has-stoped-working-windows-server-2008