# Minimum requirement for ether mining

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, ethminer

I install geth and ethminer.exe and start two exe via cmd

https://i.hizliresim.com/o6Vly9.png

is this enough for mining?If yes Where will I will get coin from mining?
Should I create wallet and sync with geth or ethminer?

I am newbie at the ether mining.I install it in windows server 2008.I am trying to learn it.If I success I will buy more better PC for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're mining to gather ether for financial gain or to use it to execute contracts on the main net, that's not the way you do it.

You got the ethminer part right. You just don't need geth unless you're trying solo mining, but that's not profitable anymore.

If you want to mine ether, the first thing you'll need is an ethereum wallet. You can get one on https://www.myetherwallet.com/ (please, ALWAYS double-check links) or an exchange (like coinbase, bittrex etc).

You'll need to mine against a mining pool, which is the best way (if not the only one) to mine widely spread coins like ether. In a nutshell, you 'sell' hashpower to a mining pool and they give you ether in return. Shares calculations varies among pools, so you'd have to check the one that best suits your needs.

Usually, there are instructions on how to set up your miner on mining pools websites. To mine against Dwarfpool (which I use), the easier way to just start mining is:

```
ethminer.exe -G -F http://eth-eu.dwarfpool.com:80/YOUR_WALLET
```

Please bear in mind that CPU mining is not profitable for ether. You'll need a GPU with at least 2GB RAM (4GB is good, 8GB is great), so the -G flag above tells ethminer to use GPU. You need to replace 'YOUR_WALLET' with your actual wallet address. You can check ethminer options by running:

```
ethminer.exe --help
```

There are several additional details to improve performance etc, but I think these are the basic instructions to get you up and running.

Comment: Thanks for answear.I am newbie.So you say no need geth( "...Geth is the program that communicates with the Ethereum Network and acts as the a relay between your computer.." )....I will uninstall geth? and you suggest me dwarfpool...I will use it.Should I create account in dwarfpool.com or no need any thing just give it to command as parameter ?  I will work for performance later.Now I just want to complete mining.I just want to get coin(amount is no matter now)... So I will reinstal geth and use dwarfpool and create wallet account.Is that true for first step?thanks

Comment: I don't use geth but it give "ethminer.exe has stopped working" error.Here is screen: https://i.hizliresim.com/o6VRM9.png

Comment: here is my command:  ethminer.exe -F http://eth-eu.dwarfpool.com:80/wallet adress(0x16.....xxxxxx

Comment: If Change port 80 to 8080 ethminer.exe -F http://eth-eu.dwarfpool.com:8080/0x16959......   it give libcurl error 28 operation timeout  here is screen: https://i.hizliresim.com/lbZ6lg.png

Comment: I open new question :(   https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29763/ethminer-exe-has-stoped-working-windows-server-2008

Comment: Sorry, I still haven't reputation to add a comment to a question, so I'll comment here... I've seen errors like these happen when I tested CPU mining. I believe it's because ethminer tries to build the DAG file in memory, but there isn't enough memory to do so. By the looks of your command, you're not using a GPU to mine... are you?

Comment: thank you for answear.I have enough memory(10 gb is free).... ethminer.exe+geth work...with out get it give that error.I use eth proxy but it still give error.I move question here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29763/ethminer-exe-has-stoped-working-windows-server-2008/29795#29795

Comment: See, the available memory I mentioned is GPU memory, not motherboard RAM. Like, if you have an intel processor with HD Graphics ethminer will try to build the DAG file within processor's GPU memory and that's what (probably) is making your ethminer crash. Believe me: you need a Graphic Processor Unit, like AMD Radeon or Nvidia to mine ehter. AFAIK you can't CPU mine it.

Comment: I just want to test it.If everything okey I will buy it.. If I use ethminer+geth it work.If I use only ethminer with mining pool(dwarfpool) with eth-proxy it give that error.... Should I use ethminer+geth with my own walllet adress ? I searched for that problem but no answear:  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29763/ethminer-exe-has-stoped-working-windows-server-2008