# Am I currently mining?

Tags: go-ethereum, solo-mining

I started mining on a regular laptop to understand a few things, before I move on to a more serious machine.

I followed the instructions as shown here: [How to Mine Ether and use Ethereum on Windows?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/110/how-to-mine-ether-and-use-ethereum-on-windows)

And I currently have these 2 windows running in parellel:

[image]
Also, at the beginning when I only start `geth --rpc` it shows Accounts: [0].
Does it mean that mining is actually working and connected to account '0'? (The only account I created?)

I am asking this because setting all of these up took only a short time, and it made me wonder maybe if it was too easy to set it up (Installing Geth, creating Geth account, running a node and installing Ethminer), then maybe something is wrong and it's not really working, but just showing some pretty running CMD code that looks like it's taken from a cool movie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the second screenshot shows you mining, it shows your hashrate.

Comment: What are the chances of me actually seeing "1" ether if I type web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), "ether") to see my balance with this hashrate? :D

Comment: zero chances - I have several Graphics cards running 24/7 i used to be a day then it was two days, then it was a week now its over a month for 1eth

Comment: But the reward isn't 5 eth? Or you mean because you're mining with a pool?

Comment: I am mining with a pool,  with my graphics cards alone I would never see any eth.